# System.CommandLine Exception Handling

Tags: c#, .net-core, dragonfruit

Is there any documentation on best practices for exception handling with System.CommandLine?

I build a handler via CommandHandler.Create and return the result of InvokeAsync from my console application.

What should I do about reporting exceptions to the user of my app? If I try/catch/log inside my handler and set Environment.ExitCode, it gets ignored of course, because I'm returning the result of InvokeAsync and my handler doesn't return anything but a task.

What is the recommended pattern for returning non-zero exit codes?

Comment: I have two articles on Exception handling in general, that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Console apps can write to STDERR and you can play games with the Error Stream.  But, yeah, it's a console app

Comment: Just checking that you indeed intended to add "dragonfruit" tag (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine.DragonFruit ? ) - unfortunately it has no information and the fact you posted no code makes it even harder to know if you are asking specific question about it or something broader (for overall ComamandLine repo, or even general command line apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CommandHandler.Create method has some overloads where you can return an `int` which is used as the ExitCode

```
public static class CommandHandler
{
    ...
    public static ICommandHandler Create(Func<int> action) =>
        HandlerDescriptor.FromDelegate(action).GetCommandHandler();

    public static ICommandHandler Create<T>(
        Func<T, int> action) =>
        HandlerDescriptor.FromDelegate(action).GetCommandHandler();
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/master/src/System.CommandLine/Invocation/CommandHandler.cs

Comment: this is what I was looking for. thanks. Is there any Exception > StdErr functionality available for System.CommandLine or am I best off just writing the exception to Console.Error myself and returning a non-zero?